# why does the code runs successfully with 'let' keyword, but not with 'var'?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, var, let

Consider the below code :

```
<button id="btn-0">Button 1!</button>
<button id="btn-1">Button 2!</button>
<button id="btn-2">Button 3!</button>
<button id="btn-3">Button 4!</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var prizes = ['Watch','A Unicorn!', 'A Hug!', 'Fresh Laundry!'];
    for (var btnNum = 0; btnNum < prizes.length-1; btnNum++) {
        // for each of our buttons, when the user clicks it...
        document.getElementById('btn-' + btnNum).onclick = function() {
            // tell her what she's won!
            alert(prizes[btnNum]);
        };
    }
</script>
```

Here, if I use 'var' for declaring variable **btnNum** in the 'for' loop, code doesn't work successfully. On clicking the buttons, each button alerts the same value which is the last element of 'prizes' array.

But if I use 'let' keyword in place of 'var', it works successfully. Now, each button on clicking shows different array element (which I want to happen). So, what's wrong with 'var' keyword here and how just replacing it with the 'let', makes everything fine?

```
<button id="btn-0">Button 1!</button>
<button id="btn-1">Button 2!</button>
<button id="btn-2">Button 3!</button>
<button id="btn-3">Button 4!</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var prizes = ['Watch','A Unicorn!', 'A Hug!', 'Fresh Laundry!'];
    for (let btnNum = 0; btnNum < prizes.length-1; btnNum++) {
        // for each of our buttons, when the user clicks it...
        document.getElementById('btn-' + btnNum).onclick = function() {
            // tell her what she's won!
            alert(prizes[btnNum]);
        };
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`var` creates a function level variable. It is *shared* by each instance of the loop. Since the clicks come later, they get whatever value the variable has after the last passage through the loop.

`let` creates a block level variable. Each time you go around the loop you get a *new* variable that belongs only to that journey through the loop.